# How to handle generics type in return type in Collection

Tags: java, java-8

I have  a case where I have to return a list of two different types based on a condition. But it always fails

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getData(true, Integer.class));
    }

    public static <E> List<E> getData(Boolean isLe, Class<E> clazz) {
        return isLe ? Arrays.asList(20) : Arrays.asList("test");
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error:(18, 36) java: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
    inference variable T has incompatible bounds
      equality constraints: E
      lower bounds: java.lang.Integer
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if I call `List<Spider> spiders = getData(true, Spider.class)`?

Comment: I expect the calculation to be based of true value of boolean but output should be List of `Spider`

Comment: But you either give back a `List<Integer>` or a `List<String>`, where would the spiders come from?

Comment: It's just an example. Hope you understand that a methods logic could be extended further. But if you talk about existing code, it should fail with unsupported return type exception (custom).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to provide the class to return a generic List with a specific type but you need to use inference of the target if  you want that it returns the required type :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T>  List<T> getData(Boolean isLe) {
    return isLe ? (List<T>)Arrays.asList(20) : (List<T>)Arrays.asList("test");
}
```

And use it :

```
List<Integer> data = getData(true);
```

or :

```
System.out.println(getData(true);
```

But this code also defeats the generic safety as the client may provide an incompatible type in the target :

```
List<Integer> data = getData(false); 
// you will get a List of String that is stored in a List of Integer
```

So your requirement seems to be inconsistent.
Either the client should decide of the generic type of the List or the method that you call should decide that. But not both.
Your logic would make sense only if the types derived from a common base class. And in this case using as generic a List of this base class would be enough.
For example :

```
public static List<Number> getData(Boolean isLe) {
    return isLe ? Arrays.asList(20) : Arrays.asList(15F);
}
```

That you could call :

```
List<Number> data = getData(false);
```

In your case, the method may return numbers or String, so you should use their base class as generic type : `Object` :

```
public static List<Object> getData(Boolean isLe) {
    return isLe ? Arrays.asList(20) : Arrays.asList(15F);
}
```

And invoke it :

```
List<Object> data = getData(false);
```

But now, what is the advantage to use a generic list that is typed with `Object` ?
No one as you will finish probably by adding downcast in the client code to use specific methods on the elements of the list.

Comment: Note that the unsafe cast may result in class cast exceptions. This method bascially removes type safety.

Comment: Your method does not use static type check. It is unchecked cast.

Comment: And [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51442236/2071828) uses rawtypes @Khemraj. Which is worse, far worse.

Comment: Yes, i am wrong, already deleted my post. I just showed him a way.

Comment: I like, how you start your answer with “*You don’t need to provide the class to return a generic List with a specific type*”, just to show, how such a method without the class argument undermines the type safety. The actual conclusion should be, you [should use only the class parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51445340/2711488).

Comment: @Holger The OP determines the generic type of the List according to a boolean condition. Your answer is valid (+1) but it also changes this requirement. Now as said in my answer : the requirement seems to be inconsistent and contradictory by the way. So according to how we twist it to make it consistent, we could get  distinct solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The `Boolean` parameter is rather obscure, after all, you already have the `clazz` parameter for describing the expected result better than a `boolean` and why `Boolean` instead of `boolean`? Do you want to support `null` values for this parameter?

You can implement the method as

```
public static <E> List<E> getData(Class<E> clazz) {
    if(clazz == Integer.class) return Arrays.asList(clazz.cast(20));
    if(clazz == String.class) return Arrays.asList(clazz.cast("test"));
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(clazz+" is neither String nor Integer");
}
```

and use it like

```
List<Integer> intList = getData(Integer.class);
System.out.println(intList);
List<String> strList = getData(String.class);
System.out.println(strList);
```

But generally, I do not recommend such a design. After all, while it’s better than having to guess the meaning of the boolean parameter, the signature still doesn’t allow a caller to recognize, which type arguments are supported.

Comment: okay! I can get rid of the boolean. The cast  of each element is porblematic for me as I can't cast 100-1000s of elements like that.

Comment: Which problem do you have when casting 1000 elements?